# Using the informs4 class with MTMI font

Tags: fonts, document-classes

I'm trying to compile the sample file `MOOR_Addition_sample-nonblindrev.tex` provided in https://pubsonline.informs.org/pb-assets/LaTeX/MOOR-style-file-2023-1696002073267.zip

However, I can't compile this file and get the following error:

`! Font MY1/mtt/m/it/10=MTMI at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found`

It seems to be a problem with the MTMI font, but in the same zip file, there is also the file MTMI.PFB, so I guess I should have access to the MTMI font.

Therefore I don't really understand the problem. Can anyone give me any hints on what to do here?

Comment: tex is looking for the .tfm not .pfb, do you have that?

Comment: No, I don't have the .tfm; is there a way of getting it somewhere?

Comment: mathtime is a commercial font collection,  but a subset is available for free from its makers: https://ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite?lang=en

Comment: It seems as if this subset is unfortunately not enough. At least I still get the same errors after installing mtp2lite (I downloaded the zip-file from the page you provided and copied the mtp2lite-directory into /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/)

Comment: I also met the same problem. When I tried to use pdflatex to compile it, it will say "mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for MTMI. mktexpk: perhaps MTMI is missing from the map file." I found the MTMI.tfm file in the zip file by the way.

Comment: Yes, it seems like they updated the zip file in the meantime; I can find the tfm files now, too. But I still can't compile and get the same problem as @William